# why I got the messy code result in my qt code about file encoding format?

Tags: c++, qt, locale

I recently want to learn how qt to encode and decode the file. I test some examples, but some make me confused.

This is my code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

#define TEST(testFile) void test##testFile()

TEST(ANSI)
{
    QFile inFile(":/test/test-ANSI.txt");
    if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    QFile outFile("../test-ANSI-bak.txt");
    if (!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
        return;

    QTextStream in(&inFile);
    QTextStream out(&outFile);
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");

    // 这样写入会去掉换行符号
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        out << line;
    }
}

TEST(GB2312)
{
    QFile inFile(":/test/test-GB2312.txt");
    if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    QFile outFile("../test-GB2312-bak.txt");
    if (!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
        return;

    QTextStream in(&inFile);
    QTextStream out(&outFile);
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");

    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        out << line;
    }
}

TEST(utf8BOM)
{
    QFile inFile(":/test/test-utf8-BOM.txt");
    if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    QFile outFile("../test-utf8-BOM-bak.txt");
    if (!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
        return;

    QTextStream in(&inFile);
    QTextStream out(&outFile);
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");

    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        out << line;
    }
}

TEST(utf8)
{
    QFile inFile(":/test/test-utf8.txt");
    if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    QFile outFile("../test-utf8-bak.txt");
    if (!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
        return;

    QTextStream in(&inFile);
    QTextStream out(&outFile);
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");

    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        out << line;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    testANSI();
    testGB2312();
    testutf8BOM();
    testutf8();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And my input text content is below:

```
----
I love you!
我爱你！
。。。
1234
1234
```

For ANSI, GB2312, utf8-BOM, I got the output file 
eg: test-ANSI-bak.txt

```
----I love you!我爱你！。。。12341234
```

For utf8, I got the output file
eg: test-utf8-bak.txt

```
----I love you!鎴戠埍浣狅紒銆傘€傘€12341234
```

Why does test-utf8-bak.txt show the messy code? I am confused that!

Comment: What if you write `out << line.toUtf8();` instead?

Comment: @vahancho Oh, it is still messy.

Comment: @vahancho QTextStream is guessing the codec based on the input file contents, for the non BOM utf-8 file it guesses incorrectly.  Thanks for Alan Birtles's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTextStream` is guessing the codec based on the input file contents, for the non BOM utf-8 file it guesses incorrectly.

You should call `in.setCodec()` if you know the format of your input files, if you don't know the format you will have to continue relying on Qt's guesses or write your own encoding detector.

It looks like QTextStream only looks for BOMs and doesn't do any other Unicode detection, from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html:

> Automatic Unicode detection is also supported. When this feature is enabled (the default behavior), QTextStream will detect the UTF-16 or the UTF-32 BOM (Byte Order Mark) and switch to the appropriate UTF codec when reading

Comment: Thank you. I know the problem now.